# Show() Hide () and removing buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very basic problem but I couldn't find the solution.

I want to be able to collapse a large chunk of text to a small summary. When the text is collapsed, there should be a button saying 'read more' which expands it, and when the text is expanded, the button should say 'collapse', which -- you guessed it -- collapses it.

I tried to use the following Javascript to achieve this. JSbin [HERE](http://jsbin.com/OsOXEzU/33/), but it's not working.

markup:

```
<div>Lore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore
    <br>lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore
    <br>lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsum
    <div id="rozwin">read more</div>
</div>
<p id="rozwijane">Lore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore
    <br>lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore
    <br>lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsum elektroniczną (Dz. U. Nr 144, poz. 1204 z późn. zm.).
    <div id="zwin">collapse</div>
```

JS:

```
$( "#zwin" ).click(function() {
    $( "#rozwijane" ).hide( "fast", function() {
        $( "#rozwin" ).show( 2000 );
        $( this ).prev().hide( "fast", arguments.callee );
    });
});

$("#rozwin" ).click(function() {
    $( "#rozwijanie" ).show( 2000 );
    $( "#zwin" ).hide( 2000 );
});
```

Comment: Will you please provide us your secret code? What have you tried so far? Make a JsFiddle?

Comment: check HERE in my post.. there is link to the jsbin.com

Comment: You should always place your code in your Post.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new here and I haven't enough time for read rules.

Comment: Note that in YOUR example, the div `#zwin` is INSIDE the `rozwijane` as revealed by a format of you jsbin markup added to the question

Comment: What does `$( "#rozwijanie" )` refer to?  Is that a typo?

Comment: `arguments.callee` is the `show` function, is that the intent?  Seems not to be correct to me.

Comment: Folks, take it easy on newbies...

Comment: @Polaris878 - seems like all valid points and questions to me for someone without time to "read the rules".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BX2S/3/)

jQuery :

```
$("#zwin").click(function () {
    $("#rozwijane").hide(2000);
    $('#zwin').hide(2000);
    $("#rozwin").show(2000);
});

$("#rozwin").click(function () {
    $("#rozwin").hide(2000);
    $("#rozwijane").show(2000);
    $("#zwin").show(2000);
});
```

CSS :

```
#rozwijane {
    display : none;
}

#zwin {
    display : none;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div>Lore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore
    <br />lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore
    <br />lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsum
</div>
<div id="rozwin">read more</div>
<p id="rozwijane">Lore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore
    <br />lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore
    <br />lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsum elektroniczną (Dz. U. Nr 144, poz. 1204 z późn.    zm.).</p>
<div id="zwin">collapse</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsbin.com/OLAwOwi/4) is a working JSBin with what I think you are trying to accomplish. If you are looking for something else, please elaborate on whate you are trying to accomplish.

Working example cf. your comment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#zwin").click(function () {
                $("#rozwijane").hide("fast", function () {
                    $("#rozwin").show(2000);
                    $("#zwin").hide(2000);
                });
            });

            $("#rozwin").click(function () {
                $("#rozwijane").show(2000);
                $("#zwin").show(2000);
                $(this).hide(2000);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title>Show/hide text</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit ...</div>
    <div id="rozwin">
        Read more</div>
    <p id="rozwijane" style="display: none;">
        Lore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore<br>
        lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore<br>
        lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsum elektroniczną (Dz. U. Nr 144, poz. 1204 z późn. zm.).</p>
        <div id="zwin" style="display: none;">
            collapse</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but first text should stay all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/chaitu18mhyd/7sspS/)

In your jsbin, you haven't closed the `p` tag properly. Also, in your script the id is `rozwijanie` but your HTML has `rozwijane`

```
$("#zwin").click(function () {
    $("#rozwijane").hide();
    $("#zwin").hide();
    $('#rozwin').show();
});

$("#rozwin").click(function () {
    $('#rozwin').hide(2000);
    $("#rozwijane").show(2000);
    $("#zwin").show(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the markup to just put the summary (at the top) portion in, then put the "additional" text in another element and toggle that "additional" text - avoids some "flashing" of the visible text, and makes it pretty easy.  Toggle the "button" text using simple logic that check current content:

Markup changes:

```
<div id="rozwi">Lore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore
    <br />lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore</div>
<div id="rozwijane">
    <br>lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsum elektroniczną (Dz. U. Nr 144, poz. 1204 z późn. zm.).
    <p>Lore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore
        <br />lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsumLore
        <br />lipsumLore lipsumLore lipsum elektroniczną (Dz. U. Nr 144, poz. 1204 z późn. zm.).</p>
</div>
<div id="zwin">show more</div>
```

Simplified code:

```
$("#rozwijane").hide();// hide expanded text initially
$("#zwin").click(function () {
    var mytext="collapse";
    var currentText= $(this).text()
    $(this).text(currentText===mytext?"show more":mytext);
    $("#rozwijane").toggle("fast");
});
```

Example in working order: http://jsfiddle.net/emF5W/